# Getting the coordinates of the Bitmap inside a Timage

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, timage

I have a TImage Control (not TImageControl) in Firemonkey. The Bitmap inside that control is centered and ocupies not the entire TImage. How can I get the coordinates of the Bitmap (Left And Top)?

Comment: Since it is centered: `Left := (Image.Width - Image.Picture.Graphic.Width) / 2;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same as @GolezTrol suggests but with integer division and a check if there is a picture assigned to the image:

```
if Assigned (Image.Picture.Graphic) then     // is there an image assigned?
  begin
  ImgX := (Image.Width - Image.Picture.Graphic.Width) div 2;
  ImgY := (Image.Height - Image.Picture.Graphic.Height) div 2;
  end;
```

Comment: Then you might consider accepting the answer. That's the SO way of saying "it works. Thanks" :)